# Duvida com função js

Tags: javascript, html

Bom dia Srs.
Primeiramente, desculpe o meu questionamento, não sou programador web e preciso fazer algo em que sou leigo.

Estou tentando dar uma "simples" manutenção em um dashboard aqui da empresa aonde eu trabalho, nele temos uma barra na lateral esquerda que podem ver a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa barra esquerda por padrão vem expandida, porém quando clicado no ícone marcado com vermelho ela se reduz ficando da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**O problema:**
Preciso fazer que o menu lateral por padrão venha de forma reduzida, e não expandido como ele vem atualmente

Conseguir identificar que o que chama a "função" (não sei como se chama) que reduz o menu é

```
<div class="nav toggle">
         <a id="menu_toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
</div>
```

Logo, fui em um arquivo .js que havia no projeto e localizei o seguinte código:

```
$(function () {
$('#sidebar-menu li ul').slideUp();
$('#sidebar-menu li').removeClass('active');

$('#sidebar-menu li').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is('.active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $('ul', this).slideUp();
        $(this).removeClass('nv');
        $(this).addClass('vn');
    } else {
        $('#sidebar-menu li ul').slideUp();
        $(this).removeClass('vn');
        $(this).addClass('nv');
        $('ul', this).slideDown();
        $('#sidebar-menu li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});

$('#menu_toggle').click(function () {
    if ($('body').hasClass('nav-md')) {
        $('body').removeClass('nav-md');
        $('body').addClass('nav-sm');
        $('.left_col').removeClass('scroll-view');
        $('.left_col').removeAttr('style');
        $('.sidebar-footer').hide();

        if ($('#sidebar-menu li').hasClass('active')) {
            $('#sidebar-menu li.active').addClass('active-sm');
            $('#sidebar-menu li.active').removeClass('active');
        }
    } else {
        $('body').removeClass('nav-sm');
        $('body').addClass('nav-md');
        $('.sidebar-footer').show();

        if ($('#sidebar-menu li').hasClass('active-sm')) {
            $('#sidebar-menu li.active-sm').addClass('active');
            $('#sidebar-menu li.active-sm').removeClass('active-sm');
        }
    }
});
});
/* Sidebar Menu active class */
$(function () {
var url = window.location;
$('#sidebar-menu a[href="' + url + '"]').parent('li').addClass('current-page');
$('#sidebar-menu a').filter(function () {
    return this.href == url;
}).parent('li').addClass('current-page').parent('ul').slideDown().parent().addClass('active')
});
```

Como consigo fazer sempre por padrão para ao abrir URL ele abrir minimizado a direita e não expandido como está funcionando atualmente?

Comment: Passa o nome desse template que ja vejo direto no código e testo. Enquanto isso vou responder com o código que eu acho q vai funcionar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já mexi com algumas telas como essa. E posso te dizer que a mágica para alterar o que você precisa está nas classes:

nav-md
e
nav-sm

inicialmente procure no seu html uma dessas classes, na sua tag body principalmente. você provavelmente encontrará nav-md, troque para nav-sm.

Depois troque em sua função js

```
$('#menu_toggle').click(function () {
```

as mesmas classes.

E teste novamente.

Comment: Excelente!
Muitíssimo obrigado, salvou o meu dia hehehehe

Comment: Ruggi, apenas uma duvida
na função js o que for md eu troco por sm e o que for sm eu troco por md?

Comment: Sem dúvida, por que isso que a função está fazendo ali. Ela troca nav-md, por nav-sm. ótimo que tenha ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Substitui:

```
$('#sidebar-menu li ul').slideUp();
```

Por:

```
$('#sidebar-menu li ul').slideDown();
```